# How to allow a client to update the textual content on a webpage through that same webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, contenteditable

Hi I have been rattling my brain for hours online trying to figure out how to allow my client to edit the textual content on the site I am creating for them all I need is a text area that can be edit directly or a seperate text box that once my client has input their text and clicked submit the textual content above is replaced with the new content. The content needs to be saved permenatly vistors to the site can see.

I am at college so I am still learning and any suggestions would be a great help thank you.

Comment: If you don't want to implement a full blown CMS, you can save the content to a database, build the page based on the content, and use something like jEditable to allow the user to change it.

Comment: Thank you is their a more simple way i looked at jEditable but i could really understand it is it possible to create a text box that is editable and saves to a database?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple way to achieve what you want. But since you tagged your question with PHP and database, i will give you an example of how to do it using these.

This is the simplest way to do it, if you want to get something more complex, you should look into getting a framework like symfony or silex.

In order to display the text to the user, you need to :

1. Connect to the mysql database
2. Fetch the message form the database table and return it in a variable

To update the text.

1. Return the text from textarea to a PHP page.
2. Connect the same way to the database.
3. Run an `UPDATE` SQL statement to change the value.

All these can be made in a single page, Look in these resources to make it:

- http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/php-mysql/
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/index.htm

Comment: if you wanted users that are on that page to see "live updates" of your client then you need some polling with ajax too

Comment: Thank you for the help this is all very confusing for me as i have not yet learnt database and only basic PHP. is their a much simpler way as my client only requires to update the content maybe once a year at the most, is their maybe a wensite that will run this for me that i can create it on their site and copy the code they give me abit like foxyform.com or emailmeform

Comment: @user3562071 If you can't use a database, you could use PHP's built-in file functions to directly modify the text files that compose the website. Start reading here: http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php, and take a look at the related functions. Of course, this would open up some blatant security risks if you actually implemented this functionality on a live website. I think the safest approach here (given the limitations) is to tell the client what parts of the file they should change (maybe in a separate document), and let them manually edit it.